# Does some condition implies convergence in a measure?

Tags: analysis

Let $f_n$ (for $n=1,2,...$) and  $f$ be   measurable real valued functions on a space $X$ with a finite measure $\mu$. Let's assume that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|f_n-f\|=0$, where

$$\|f_n-f\|=\inf_{\alpha >0} (\alpha+\mu\{x: |f_n(x)-f(x)|> \alpha \}).$$

Does $(f_n)$ tend to $f$ with respect to the measure $\mu$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $N$ so that for all $n > N$ we have $\|f_n - f\| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. By definition of the supremum we can find an $\alpha > 0$ with 
$$\alpha  + \mu(|f_n - f| > \alpha) < \|f_n - f\| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \le \varepsilon.$$

But this means that $\alpha \le \varepsilon$ and we can conclude
$$\mu(|f_n - f| > \varepsilon) \le \mu(|f_n - f| > \alpha) \le \alpha + \mu(|f_n - f| > \alpha) \le \varepsilon,$$

i.e. $f_n \to f$ in measure.

Comment: Many thanks for answer.